# UIView animation options using Swift

Tags: uiviewanimation, swift

How do I set the `UIViewAnimationOptions` to `.Repeat` in an `UIView` animation block:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay:0.2 , options: UIViewAnimationOptions, animations: (() -> Void), completion: (Bool) -> Void)?)
```

Answer (score 108, accepted):

#### Swift 3

Pretty much the same as before:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.repeat, animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

except that you can leave out the full type:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.2, options: .repeat, animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

and you can still combine options:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.repeat, .curveEaseInOut], animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

#### Swift 2

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: {}, completion: nil)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: .Repeat, animations: {}, completion: nil)

UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Things changed again in Swift 3. Might look like this in Swift 3: `options: [.allowUserInteraction, .beginFromCurrentState],`

Comment: How about swift 4?

Answer (score 13):

Most of the Cocoa Touch 'option' sets that were enums prior to Swift 2.0 have now been changed to structs, `UIViewAnimationOptions` being one of them.

Whereas `UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat` would previously have been defined as:

(semi-pseudo code)

```
enum UIViewAnimationOptions {
  case Repeat
}
```

It is now defined as:

```
struct UIViewAnimationOption {
  static var Repeat: UIViewAnimationOption
}
```

Point being, in order to achieve what was achieved prior using bitmasks (`.Reverse | .CurveEaseInOut`) you'll now need to place the options in an array, either directly after the `options` parameter, or defined in a variable prior to utilising it:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: [.Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut], animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

or

```
let options: UIViewAnimationOptions = [.Repeat, .CurveEaseInOut]
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, delay: 0.2, options: options, animations: {}, completion: nil)
```

Please refer to the following answer from user @0x7fffffff for more information: [Swift 2.0 - Binary Operator “|” cannot be applied to two UIUserNotificationType operands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30763344/1353809)

Comment: You know you could have just slightly edited the answer … :)

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, delay: 0, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut, animations: {}, completion: nil)
```