# Adding two UIViewAnimationOptions to an animation (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have this code for animating a table:

```
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut | UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction, animations: { () -> Void in

    self.myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: offSetY), animated: false)


    }, completion: nil)
```

I want to have the additional option `UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction` but I get the error: "| cannot be applied to two UIViewAnimationOptions operands". How can I add this? Works in objective-c.

Comment: For more details, check this (identiqual) thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081192/uiview-animation-options-using-swift?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Swift 2` you have to write in this way. The `OptionSetType` has an updated syntax.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.33, delay: 0, options:[UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction], animations: { () -> Void in

        self.myTableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 8), animated: false)


        }, completion: nil)
```

Comment: ahh, in an array got it thanks! Give me a min and I'll accept your answer